# How to find element of table row with css and vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want every other row to be gray, but in the following example - all rows become gray.

```
  <table>    
    <tr v-for="i in item.env_vars" :style="{'background': index % 2 === 0 ? '#eee' : '#ccc' }">
      <td> test1 </td>
      <td> test2 </td>
      <td> test3 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

and I see this error in vue admin tool:

```
Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: How do you create your multiple `<tr>`s? The answer depends on that. Your current code only has one `<tr>`

Comment: There is no for-loop here so I don't understand where are you getting the `index` from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with vue, but I think you need to add an `index` variable to your loop:

```
<tr v-for="(i, index) in item.env_vars"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) rule:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not able to do this due to some restraints of the project I am working on.  the css needs to be per vue component - that''s why im trying to programmatically create it .